# Having an issue calculating age using csv file without importing it completely into memory

Tags: python, function, csv, datetime, with-statement

I keep getting the following error. don't know how to fix it.

```
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable
```

.....

```
def median_age(filename):
    
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        
        data = csv.reader(file,delimiter = '\t')
        
        next(data) # Skips the header of the csv file
        
        customer_age = (2024 - int(data['birth_year']) for row in data)
        
        median_customer_age = statistics.median(customer_age)
        
        return median_customer_age
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

- With csv.reader object, each row is a list of the field values.
- Since you desire to reference values by fieldnames you should use DictReader which provides a dictionary rather than a list.
- DictReader maps the information in each row to a dictionary
  whose keys correspond to the fieldnames.

**Code**

```
import csv
from statistics import median

def median_age(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter = '\t')

    # Generator for ages
    # row is dictonary of fieldnames/values pairs
    customer_age = (2024 - int(row['birth_year']) for row in reader)
             
    return median(customer_age)
```

**Example Usage**

*Input File:* data.csv

```
first   last    birth_year
paul    henry   2019
bill    thompson    1995
mary    allen   2003
jennifer    davis   2015
liz morgan  1999
```

*Test Code*

```
median_customer_age = median_age('data.csv')
print(f'File data.csv median age: {median_customer_age}')
```

*Output*

```
File data.csv median age: 21
```